# Declare delegate when using ARC

Tags: iphone, ios6, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

In fastpdfkit has delegate declaration like this

```
@interface BookmarkViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

//Delegate to get the current page and tell to show a certain page. It can also be used to
//  get a list of bookmarks for the current document. 

NSObject<BookmarkViewControllerDelegate> *delegate; 
 }

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<BookmarkViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;

@synthesize delegate;
```

As i m using ARC so declaration of delegate is like this

```
@interface BookmarkViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

 id __unsafe_unretained <BookmarkViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
 }

@property (unsafe_unretained) id <BookmarkViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

 @synthesize delegate;
```

Is it correct cause when i m debugging i m getting

```
 currentPage    NSUInteger  0
delegate    objc_object *   0x00000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heres a pattern to follow.  The delegate is properly declared weak (an object but with no transfer of ownership or increase in retain count).

```
@protocol MyClassDelegate;

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property(weak, nonatomic) id<MyClassDelegate>delegate;

@end

@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myClass:(MyClass *)myClass didSomethingAtTime:(NSDate *)time;
- (CGSize)sizeofSomethingNeededByMyClass:(MyClass *)myClass;

// and so on

@end
```